# Flask - Auto render_template to list or urls

Tags: flask

I have been trying to use flask to auto move to another url based on a list or url's/page names. The idea is anyone can throw in a page, add to the list and the site will continue moving to each page every 30 seconds or so.

This is my pseudo code

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

list = ["1.html", "2.html"]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    for li in list:
       return render_template(li)
       time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have tried a few different ways but effectively the @app.route will only run once. If I run the loop outside the @app.route I m trying to write over an endpoint.

Any suggestions different approaches?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it. Using some global variables and realising that the function will not update variables outside of its function. This will go through a list of web pages and move to each one after a period of time.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

list1 = ["1.html", "2.html", '3.html']

i = 0

@app.route('/')
def index():
    global i
    if i < len(list1):
        j = i
        i+=1
        return render_template(list1[j])
    elif (i == len(list1)):
        i = 0
        return render_template(list1[i])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You also need to add the following to each html page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" >
```

This will force a refresh which runs the function. So now basically I can have a slide show of pages and all people will need to do is add the page in the directory, add the page name to a list (which will be a text file) and it will show the page of the next interation.